# Laravel @ hide in blade view records from SQL if True

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I cannot understand, how to hide/do not show records from SQL if the status of one or more is XXX

Example:

I have SQL table called - projects, and one project has status - CLOSED.

My blade view will display this project together with projects who has status - OPEN

How I can hide if project is Closed?

THankx

Comment: You can use `@if()` to check a condition in `.blade.php` files. For example: `@if($project->status !== "closed"){{ $project->name }}@endif`. Try to include some code in your question so we have more to work with though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude all projects with a status of closed, you can return the filtered collection in your controller:

```
$projects = Project::where('status', '<>', 'closed')->get();
```

Better yet, create a local scope on the `Project` model:

```
public function scopeOpen($query) {
    return $query->where('status', 'open');
}
```

And then use it later:

```
$projects = Project::open();
```